# multithreading, start, join -java

Tags: java, multithreading

What is wrong with doing this? I'm currently learning about threads

```
thread1.start();
thread1.join();
thread2.start();
thread2.join();
```

EDIT: I know this is an error, as it's in the source that I'm learning from. However, the source does not provide an answer as to why it's wrong

And what is the difference between using and not using .join on a thread?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? Do you understand what that does?

Comment: Do you understand what `.join()` does? Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to start new thread and then join it right away. `join()` will halt current thread until the other finishes. This would have the same effect as writting:

```
thread1.run();
thread2.run();
```

The author probably meant:

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```

This way `thread1` and `thread2` can execute at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you put that in try/catch it's not an error, but there will be a question why you want to do that and use thread? this will wait until `thread1` dead and then started to work with `thread2`. this example from [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example-with-explanation) will be good for you to understand concept of `join()` (read the comment they explain it very good) :

```
    t1.start();

    //start second thread after waiting for 2 seconds or if it's dead
    try {
        t1.join(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    t2.start();

    //start third thread only when first thread is dead
    try {
        t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    t3.start();

    //let all threads finish execution before finishing main thread
    try {
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to judge is it an error or not. It depends from what are you doing in threads thread1 and thread2 and what are you trying to achieve.

From Java Documentation:

```
thread1.join();
```

causes the current thread to pause execution until thread1's thread terminates.

If you are trying to launch two thread concurrently then this is a problem, because threads will be launched consecutively.